# How to save the autoID to the created child?

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I've read a lot of articles on this website, which were focusing on writing data to the Firebase Database. However, none of them could solve my problem.

I've created an object with an autoID, however to delete it later on, I need the autoID I've created the object with. For that reason I need to save the autoID to that object. It just doesn't work out.

Here is the code:

@IBAction func Save(_ sender: Any) {

```
    let Town = Stadt.text
    let surface = Untergrund.text
    let size = Groesse.text
    let numberof = AnzToreKoerbe.text
    let laenge = longitudeLabel.text
    let breite = latitudeLabel.text
    let street = Strasse.text
    let Art = Platzart.text
    var PlatzID = ""


    var upload : [String : AnyObject] = ["Platzart": Art as AnyObject,
                                         "Laengengrad" : laenge as AnyObject,
                                         "Breitengrad" : breite as AnyObject,
                                         "Stadt" : Town as AnyObject,
                                         "Strasse" : street as AnyObject,
                                         "Untergrund" : surface as AnyObject,
                                         "Groesse" : size as AnyObject,
                                         "AnzahlToreKoerbe" : numberof as AnyObject,
                                         "PlatzID" : PlatzID as AnyObject]


    ref?.child("Sportplatz").childByAutoId().setValue(upload)

    PlatzID = (ref?.key)!

    ref?.updateChildValues(["PlatzID" : PlatzID as AnyObject])
```

I've tried to save the key, as some of the articles recommended and then update the child "PlatzID" with that key. 
When I create a new object, the PlatzID ist still empty.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: whenever you register a user in your app using the FIRAuth class, in the completion handler you will get an `authData ` object. This object contains a unique ID e,g `authData.uid`. This ID represents the hash value for the email address of the user. You can get this uid value after your user logs in your app with user and password and then use it later to write/read/update your Firebase Database. So your Firebase DB should look like:   Users/the uid received when the customer logs in/ and other objects which you are saving in DB.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However I haven' created my object with FIRAuth. I want to use the auto id or create something similar, that i can save. I desperatly need that id to be able to delete them from the database!

Comment: The only solution I can see is to query the db, get all objects and then select the object(s) you want to display and delete. Otherwise, you cannot retrieve something you don't know. Firebase tree is a JSON object of key:value pairs. Your key is the generated autoID, so you cannot get the value of a key that you don't know. Think about it this way, I hide 2 apples behind my back, one is read, the other is green. How can you get the green apple? 1 you ask me to show you both hands ( you query the db and get key:value pairs) 2. you know in which hand I have the green/red one. Hope it makes sense

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not sure if this can help you + I am a bit late with the answer, but you can get and save autoID like this:

```
let randomID = Database.database().reference().childByAutoId()
print(randomID.key)
```

Comment: thanks for your late answer, I just saw this approach a few days ago as well, but thanks anyway!